# equality comparison between two operands in which one operand may be undefined

Tags: javascript

```
if (typeof operand1 != "undefined" && operand1 == operand2) {
}
```

Above is an `if` statement that checks for the equality between *operand1* and *operand2*, where *operand1* may be `undefined` under some scenario. I wonder if the `typeof operand1 != "undefined"` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use the `==` operator and not the `===` operator, it's unnecessary only if `operand2` will never be `null`.

But you can change the `if statement` to use the `===` operator which then will pass only if `operand2` "really equals" to `operand1`, meaning `operand2` is `undefined` as well.

You can read more about it here:
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dEHz/2/) that shows what was written here.

---

In the `Data Base`world, `null`(or `undefined`) is nothing, which means you can't compare it to anything.

**SQL example:**

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
Where  t.operand1 = null
```

is an error because nothing equals to null, and null doesn't equal to anything, it just doesn't exist.

**In `javascript` it is not like that**, you can compare things to `null` and `undefined`, but you have to be careful with `TypeError`s, like with this:

```
var x;
x.foo; // TypeError!
```

Comment: Your last example is incorrect. It would be `TypeError`, as `undefined` does and can not have properties.

Comment: @gdoron can you please elaborate on what you mean by "it's unnecessary only if operand2 will never be a falsy value"? Say operand2 can be a falsy value, I would like to see an example where 'typeof operand1 != "undefined"' is necessary. Thx

Comment: @ahmoo. There was a little mistake in the answer, I fixed it. anyway you can see an example in the DEMO I added to my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: @gdoron - yes, the example and your further explanation have made everything clear now. Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I'd say it's necessary to do that `typeof` check before checking the equality of two variables' values is when one of them (`operand1`) may not be defined, preventing a `ReferenceError`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmTaA/).

Comment: @gdoron I didn't say `undefined`, I said *not defined*, as in, there is no variable named `operand1` in the scope chain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have brought up a good point. I only wish I could accept more than one answer.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your fiddle. It would still get ReferenceError even if `typeof operand1 != "undefined"` is there.

Comment: @ahmoo The fiddle was to demonstrate the `ReferenceError`. Try uncommenting out the bits I commented.